# How to run a randomly selected function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run a random function but haven't quite figured it out:

```
<script>

function randomFrom(array) {return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];}

function randomchords(){randomFrom(['poop()', 'poop2()', 'poop3()']);}               



function poop() { $(function() {ionian_c_vi() });  }                          

function poop2() {  $(function() {ionian_c_iii() }), $(function() {ionian_c_iv() });  }                      

function poop3() { $(function() {ionian_c_vi() }), $(function() {ionian_c_i() }), $(function() {ionian_c_ii() });  }  

</script>
```

and then:

```
<button onclick="randomchords()" >Get some random chords</button>
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: What does the `poop()` function return?

Comment: Just stick some eval's in there and you'll be golden! +1 on the poop functions BTW.

Comment: It draws ukulele chords with Raphael!  When it's done it will spit out random chord progressions.

Comment: What's that got to do with poop ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option is to use `window` object:

```
function randomchords() {
    var func = randomFrom(['poop', 'poop2', 'poop3']);
    window[func]();
}
```

Pay attention that you should remove parentheses from function names in the array.

---

Another option is to remove quotes from the variant above and call functions directly:

```
function randomchords() {
    var func = randomFrom([poop, poop2, poop3]);
    (func)();
}
```

Comment: ...but maybe its better to store the function in their own object, not on the global one.

Comment: @Bergi Possibly yes but the solution will be almost the same.

Comment: Why the strings? Why not just `randomFrom([poop, poop2, poop3])()`?

Answer (score 6):

Functions are like values. You could say:

```
var myArray = [
    function(){
        ionian_c_vi();
    },
    function(){
        ionian_c_iii();
        ionian_c_iv()
    },
    function(){
        ionian_c_vi();
        ionian_c_i();
    }
];
function randomchords(){ 
     randomFrom(myArray).call();
}
```

For more info, look at http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/02/24/video-crockonjs-3/ and/or read at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call

Bookwise, read Javascript: The Good Parts (120 pages)

Helps learn JS outside jQuery :)

Comment: Better! But the `call` is still superfluous, `randomFrom(myArray)()` is fine.

Comment: It is true that it's superfluous, it's more like a personal choice of style - it denotes that I expect something "callable". I use call or apply always when requesting function references.

Answer (score 1):

You're quite close:

```
function foo() { ... }
function bar() { ... }
function baz() { ... }
```

These functions are defined to the global scope, which is usually `window` within a browser.
You can access them via string by calling `window['foo']` for example. That will return the `foo` function itself (not the value from execution).

```
function randomFrom(array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

function randomchords() {
  // add the 'window' prefix here
  randomFrom(window['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])();
}
```

Comment: I would have upvoted this if you didn't tell that nonsense about Math.random().

Comment: D'oh, corrected my mistake after some reading. I thought `Math.random()` would be `0 <= x <= 1` but apparently is `0 <= x < 1` ... so forget about that _being careful_ part :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do this many way:

But the easiest i think to generate a random number, and call functions with case :)

```
$("button").click(function)
{
    var n = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    switch(n)
    {
        case: 0:
        Function0();
        break;

        case: 1:
        Function1();
        break;

        case: 2:
        Function2();
        break;

        ...

        case: 10:
        Function10();
        break;
}
```

With btn you can call

```
<button>Get some random chords</button>
```