# Run JavaScript function 70% of the time, randomly selected from an array of functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random

I've seen [How to run a randomly selected function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693488/how-to-run-a-randomly-selected-function-in-javascript) which allows for running a JavaScript function randomly selected from at array with an equal chance each time (e.g. if there are two functions in total, there is a 50% chance that each function will be executed each time).

How to write a function to state the percentage chance of executing each function that is randomly available to be chosen from an array of functions? **How do I do a weighted randomization??**

```
function randomFrom(array) {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}
var contentWrapper = function (target,type,articleId) {
  // list type ads
  if (type == 'list') {
    function randomListData() {
      var func = randomFrom([
        function () {
          fnNameA10(target, 'list');
        },
        function () {
          fnNameB20(target, 'list', articleId);
        }
      ]);
      (func)();
    }
    randomListData();
    // content type ads
  } else if (type == 'content') {
    function randomContentData() {
      var func = randomFrom([
        function () {
          fnNameA10(target, 'content');
        },
        function () {
          fnNameB20(target, 'content', articleId);
        }
      ]);
      (func)();
    }
    randomContentAd();
  }
};
```

Comment: Do you mean that the function should take in `{function:percentage}` as input?

Comment: ...by asking your instructor to see the answer key?

Comment: Are you trying to do weighted randomization?

Comment: Are you asking how to determine the chance that a function will be called given a equal weighting OR are you asking how to weight a functions chance of being called?

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes, exactly.

Comment: @sPaz that would be awesome, but how do I do that?

Comment: @Steve see this for examples: http://codetheory.in/weighted-biased-random-number-generation-with-javascript-based-on-probability/

Comment: @sPaz, thanks again! Method 2 works great. If you want to paste it and reference the link, I'll mark/accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://codetheory.in/weighted-biased-random-number-generation-with-javascript-based-on-probability/) is your answer:

```
var rand = function(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};

var getRandomItem = function(list, weight) {
    var total_weight = weight.reduce(function (prev, cur, i, arr) {
        return prev + cur;
    });

    var random_num = rand(0, total_weight);
    var weight_sum = 0;
    //console.log(random_num)

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        weight_sum += weight[i];
        weight_sum = +weight_sum.toFixed(2);

        if (random_num <= weight_sum) {
            return list[i];
        }
    }

    // end of function
};

var list = ['javascript', 'php', 'ruby', 'python'];
var weight = [0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1];
var random_item = getRandomItem(list, weight);
```

Comment: I liked your original setup sPaz.

Comment: @Emmentaler I didn't know your answer was accepted already. :P Here, take my upvote...

Comment: @sPaz, in fairness you provided a working solution (in the comments) few seconds before Emmentaler and I promised to accept your answer if you submitted one. Thanks again. :)

Comment: I think that is fair.  I borrowed his start anyway :-)

Answer (score 3):

http://plnkr.co/edit/wzKp8PqNJ4Fmyo2504Cu?p=preview

```
var funcs = [
  {probability: 20, fn: function(){console.log("20%")}},
  {probability: 10, fn: function(){console.log("10%")}},
  {probability: 70, fn: function(){console.log("70%")}}
];

var total = 0;
var n = Math.random();
for(var i=0; i<funcs.length; ++i) {
  total+=funcs[i].probability;
  if(n*100<total) {
    funcs[i].fn.call(this);
    break;
  }
}
```

Here I am getting a random number between 0 and 1 then determining where that number falls in array.  I do this by stacking the percentages up and comparing the number to the total amount.  I need the `break` because every element in the array will come back true once the condition is met and I only want the first one.