# Select random method

Tags: javascript, function, random

I have my JavaScript code and one file with a lot of different functions (a few hundred). I want to create a new function (same file or different file) that will randomly execute one of the existing functions.

One of the problems is there isn't a naming pattern that can be identified, I would need to have it pick any function from a file. Maybe by identifying a line and checking if the keyword function is present?

Due to the number of functions and the need to add more, an array is not possible. I need to have the function be treated as an unknown variable.

Comment: How are the functions organised in the existing code module? Are you able to modify the existing code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a randomly selected function in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693488/how-to-run-a-randomly-selected-function-in-javascript)

Comment: I do have the ability to edit the code, however being over 300 functions long, finding a way without editing them is preferable.

The "How to run a randomly selected function in JavaScript?" Is different as it uses an array of the functions and randomly selects from the array. Putting all 300+ functions into an array would be impractical, plus more functions will eventually be added that need to be considered also.

Comment: can you provide snippet of how you specified the functions

Comment: The functions to select from are mostly displayed mostly alphabetical, named alpha-numeric, all start their name with "to" but after that, there is no identifiable pattern.

Ex)<br/>
toApple = function<br/>
toBunny = function<br/>
toCar = function<br/>
toDirtySocks = function<br/>
...

Comment: toApple = function{}                                                 
toBunny = function{}                                        
toCar = function{}                                                    
toDirtySocks = function{}                                            
...

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the easiest / cleanest way would be to have all the functions stored in object like:

```
var myFunctions: {
    fn1: function() {},
    fn2: function() {},
    fn3: function() {}
    // ...
}
```

Then you can do `var fnNames = Object.keys(myFunctions)` which will give you all your functions names as an array.

Then you can do: `myFunctions[fnNames[Math.floor(Math.random()*fnNames.length)]]`

Or longer and cleaner version:

```
var randomFunctionNameIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*fnNames.length);
var randomFunctionName = fnNames[randomFunctionNameIndex];
var randomFunction = myFunctions[randomFunctionName];

var result = randomFunction();
```

Comment: Listing every function isn't practical, I like the idea, but it will have to leave the functions as unknown variables

Comment: The function are still somewhere, like global context (`window`), you can get keys from there but there will be much more keys present, what is your context?

Comment: Not sure what the question is "context"??  Is there a way to pull all the key for all functions in one file but not another file?

Comment: It's using node.js to run in browsers

Comment: Well that didnt make much sense ? You mean browserify ? Put snippet on plunker or jsfiddle or somewhere

Comment: Yes, we follow the same structure as browserify

Comment: how are the function defined in the file ? `var something = function()` or `function Something()`

Comment: if you wrap all your function in one function `function() { //... all your functions here }` then you can access them by `Object.keys(this)` inside of the function and then you can use code in answer.

Comment: they are all in the var something = function() {insert function code here}

Comment: Yeah just wrap it in a function like written in comment above and it should be accessible by `Object.keys(this)`, inside of the function. Did you try it ?